# How to run an XmlReader in parallel in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, parallel-processing, f#

I have a potentially large xml document to read into memory in the most performant way possible. The structure of the document is that it containst a large number of fairly simple xml elements.

Prior research and testing (single threaded) has shown that XmlReader is the most performance oriented class to use.

The nodes/elements I am interested in are small in and of themselves and don't require too much processing such that about 60% of the time is spent just doing the `xmlReader.Read()` command moving to the next node.

What kind of approach could I take to bring parallelism to bear on this problem st performance will be improved (more than the overhead that parallelism will bring)?

One half formed idea I have is that if there was a way to **efficiently** divide the xml into large chunks st it could be fed into different worker threads...but I'm not sure how to divide the document without parsing it!

## Example XML

Extract taken from the body of one of the main xml files in an Excel spreadsheet. I am interested in the "c" elements:

```
<row r="1" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A1"><v>1</v></c></row>
<row r="2" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A2"><f>A1+1</f><v>2</v></c></row>
<row r="3" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A3"><f t="shared" ref="A3:A66" si="0">A2+1</f><v>3</v></c></row>
<row r="4" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A4"><f t="shared" si="0"/><v>4</v></c></row>
<row r="5" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A5"><f t="shared" si="0"/><v>5</v></c></row>
<row r="6" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A6"><f t="shared" si="0"/><v>6</v></c></row>
<row r="7" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A7"><f t="shared" si="0"/><v>7</v></c></row>
<row r="8" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A8"><f t="shared" si="0"/><v>8</v></c></row>
<row r="9" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.4"><c r="A9"><f t="shared" si="0"/><v>9</v></c></row>
```

Comment: XML just simply doesn't lend itself to parallelism, because it requires a root element. Do you have the power to switch formats? Perhaps transmit child elements without the root? Also: from where are you reading it? Do you have random access to that medium?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Reading one of the inner files (xml) of an Excel file (xlsx) from local disk. The xlsx format is just a zip of a bunch of xml files.

Comment: Ok, ZIP file means sequential access. In that case, your only hope for parallelism is to extract that file and put it on a disk somewhere first, but that would require scanning it sequentially anyway, so defeats the purpose. I would try to look at better parsing strategies. Perhaps roll your own parser? Since you have F# tag there, you could try FParsec.

Comment: If you google "xml parallel processing" you'll find a few examples of chunking approaches, but none of them are very easy. Also, does using ReadAsync() make a difference?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the document? IE does a parser have to be able to handle any XML document or could it make assumptions that simplify the parsing process. Full XML spec contains lots of special cases for character classes which complicates parsing (and therefore hurts performance). Could you post some samples?

Comment: @FuleSnabel I have provided a sample above. I am essentially trying to get the contents of the cells (of the spreadsheet) into memory for further processing.

Comment: If the XML is really simple and predictable, maybe you could just ditch the xmlreader and parse everything manually?

Comment: @Sam I will take a look at it. Another thing to consider is the SAX parser that is part of MSXML. SAX parsers reduces parsing overhead by letting the user implement a visitor interface. But MSXML is COM based and I think the COM interop introduces overhead

Comment: @JohnPalmer My reason for not going down that route is that the xml file structure does not appear to have many lines (2 lines: one for header info & one for the all the **data**). Even for a huge file, all the data I am interested in is on one line which will mean having to read the whole thing into memory (not streaming) and then parsing one huge string (as opposed to millions of smaller strings).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Parallel LINQ to XML to access your XML in parallel.